# Java.Util Linked List Implementation from Scratch

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I would like to implement a singly linkedlist with functions that the java.util library does not contain such as: returning the middle node in a linked list and inserting a new head at the linkedlist. My question is: What type of linked list is the java.util linked list (eg. singly, doubly)? Secondly, I would be interested in knowing if you recommend me to implement linked lists from scratch. I care about being able to maintain my own code without third party libraries (because of the dependency) and being able to customise it. I also want to implement merge sort and I feel that having a middle node method is important. Thanks!!

Comment: `java.util.LinkedList` doesn't expose direct access to nodes, but you can get access to e.g. the middle node via the `listIterator`.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by direct nodes (i.e. what can you not access)? @LouisWasserman

Comment: There isn't, like, a public `Node` class you can access.

Comment: But isn't that redundant? When would you need to access it? The library is a generic linked list.. @LouisWasserman

Comment: That's right, you don't.  That's...kind of the point?  I'm suggesting that `LinkedList` might already be able to do what you want through its various APIs.

Comment: I think that in the end you will be more satisfied with `ArrayList` and its `sort` method than with any singly or doubly linked list, be it your own or the one from the library.

Answer (score 0):

The Java implementation of [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html) is a doubly-linked list.  Also, it already has the ability to add an element at the head/front (if I understood correctly).

Linked lists are relatively simple, so you can implement them from scratch if you like (there are plenty of tutorials if you do a simple search as well).  However, if a third-party open source library meets your needs, I would highly recommend using it.  It is likely to be far better maintained than anything you can manage.  If you think it is falling behind or lacking, you can offer contributions.

For merge sort, not sure why you need it.  Java collections already implements [merge sort](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator)), and uses the most efficient and up to date algorithms available.